# can not show alertcontroller when page is displayed using PushModalAsync

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show toast message in android and iOS from xamarin.forms project using Dependency Service. In iOS project message is shown on MainPage or NavigationPage. but when I navigate a second page on button click using PushModalAsync, message is not displayed.

How I navigate the page

```
public LoginPage()
{
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    CustomToast.LongMessage("Hiiiiii");  // Message shown
                });

 Navigation.PushModalAsync(new RegisterPage());   //Doesn't show
//var reg = new RegisterPage();
//Application.Current.MainPage = reg;  // toast shown here
}
```

Code for alertController in iOS :

```
        const double SHORT_DELAY = 2.0;

        NSTimer alertDelay;
        UIAlertController alert;

        public void LongAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, LONG_DELAY);
        }
        public void ShortAlert(string message)
        {
            ShowAlert(message, SHORT_DELAY);
        }

        void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
        {
            try
            {
                if (alert == null && alertDelay == null)
                {
                    alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            DismissMessage();
                        });
                    });

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            alert = UIAlertController.Create("", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
                            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            var Error = ex.Message;
                        }                        
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceLog("Message iOS ShowAlert : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void DismissMessage()
        {
            if (alert != null)
            {
                alert.DismissViewController(true, null);
                alert = null;
            }
            if (alertDelay != null)
            {
                alertDelay.Dispose();
                alertDelay = null;
            }
        }
```

And I call this from my register page constructor

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    CustomToast.LongMessage("Hiiiiii");
                });
```

It doesn't go in catch anywhere but its not displayed also. can anyone please suggest some advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `RegisterPage` is a presented page on your `LoginPage`, `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController` this code can't retrieve a correct view controller for `RegisterPage`. It just presented an action sheet on the previous page, but your app has reached a new page then this **Toast** can be shown on the screen.
Firstly, you have to find out the top page on the window:

```
UIViewController topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController)
{
    if (rootViewController is UITabBarController)
    {
        UITabBarController tabBarController = (UITabBarController)rootViewController;
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.SelectedViewController);
    }
    else if (rootViewController is UINavigationController)
    {
        UINavigationController navigationController = (UINavigationController)rootViewController;
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.VisibleViewController);
    }
    else if (rootViewController.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        UIViewController presentedViewController = rootViewController.PresentedViewController;
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController);
    }
    return rootViewController;
}
```

Secondly, adjust your presenting code like:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        alert = UIAlertController.Create("", messages, UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet);
        topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController).PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var Error = ex.Message;
    }
});
```

At last, you could show your toast using `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new RegisterPage());`